# Sessionized web logs, get previous and next domain

Tags: session, hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

We have a large pile of web log data.  We need to sessionize it, and also generate the previous domain, and next domain for each session. I am testing via an interactive job flow on AWS EMR.

Right now I'm able to get the data sessionized using this code here: http://goo.gl/L52Wf . It took a little work to get familiar with compiling and using a UDF, but I've made it that far.

Here is the header row and first line from the input file (tab delimited):

```
ID  Date    Rule code   Project UID respondent_uid  Type    Tab ID  URL domain  URL path    Duration    Exit cause  Details
11111111    2012-09-25T11:21:20.000Z    20120914_START_USTEST   20120914_TESTSITE_US_TR test6_EN_9  PAGE_VIEWED FF1348568479042 http://www.google.fr        11  OTHER
```

This is a tuple from the `SESSIONS` relation (steps to get relation are shown below):

```
(2012-09-27 04:42:20.000,11999603,20120914_URL_ALL,20120914_TESTSITE_US_TR,2082810875_US_9,PAGE_VIEWED,CH17,http://hotmail.com,_news/2012/09/26/14113684,28,WINDOW_DEACTIVATED,,3019222a-5c4d-4767-a82e-2b4df5d9db6d)
```

This is roughly what I'm running right now to sessionize the test data:

```
register s3://TestBucket/Sessionize.jar

define Sessionize datafu.pig.sessions.Sessionize('30m');

A = load 's3://TestBucket/party2.gz' USING PigStorage() as (id: chararray, data_date: chararray, rule_code: chararray, project_uid: chararray, respondent_uid: chararray, type: chararray, tab_id: chararray, url_domain: chararray, url_path: chararray, duration: chararray, exit_cause: chararray, details: chararray);

B = foreach A generate $1, $0, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11;

C = filter B by id neq 'ID';

VIEWS = group C by (respondent_uid, url_domain);

SESSIONS = foreach VIEWS { VISITS = order C by data_date; generate FLATTEN(Sessionize(VISITS)) as (data_date: chararray, id: chararray, rule_code: chararray, project_uid: chararray, respondent_uid: chararray, type: chararray, tab_id: chararray, url_domain: chararray, url_path: chararray, duration: chararray, exit_cause: chararray, details: chararray, session_id); }
```

(The step at B is to move the date to the first position. Step at C is to filter out the file header)

I'm lost as far as the right direction to go with this from here.

Can I iterate over my `SESSIONS` relation with `foreach` and get next and previous domain from pig script?  Would it be better to write a custom UDF and pass the `SESSIONS` relation to that? (Writing my own UDF would be an adventure!..)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Even if someone could recommend what **NOT** to do, might be just as helpful, so I don't waste time researching a junk approach. I'm quite new to Hadoop and pig script so this is definitely not one of my strong areas (yet..).

Comment: Could you provide some input and output data?

Comment: @alexeipab I added an example of input data, as well as an example of a tuple from `SESSIONS` relation.  The output doesn't exist yet, I'll need to have `respondent_uid`, `session_id` with next domain and previous domain.  I could group the `SESSIONS` relation, but I'm uncertain how to get next and previous. If I can provide any other helpful information please let me know

Comment: Just an update. I'm attempting to go the UDF route right now. I'll continue to update as progress and failures occur.

Comment: I have a not-so-pretty UDF solution working! Once I clean it up, and make a few tweaks, I'll add it as an answer for anyone else who runs into something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't at all be surprised if someone could improve on the solution below, however, **it works** for my situation. I used the sessionize UDF (mentioned in my question) as a reference for writing the below UDF.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.pig.Accumulator;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class PreviousNext extends EvalFunc<DataBag> implements Accumulator<DataBag>
{

    private DataBag outputBag;
    private String previous;
    private String next;

    public PreviousNext()
    {
        cleanup();
    }

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException 
    {   
        accumulate(input);
        DataBag outputBag = getValue();
        cleanup();

        return outputBag;
    }

    @Override
    public void accumulate(Tuple input) throws IOException 
    {
        ArrayList<String> domains = new ArrayList<String>();

        DataBag d = (DataBag)input.get(0);

        //put all domains into ArrayList to allow for
        //accessing specific indexes
        for(Tuple t : d)
        {
            domains.add((String)t.get(2));
        }

        //add empty string for "next domain" value for last iteration
        domains.add("");

        int i = 0;

        previous = "";

        for(Tuple t : d)
        {   
            next = domains.get(i+1);

            Tuple t_new = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(t.getAll());

            t_new.append(previous);
            t_new.append(next);

            outputBag.add(t_new);

            //current domain is previous for next iteration
            previous = domains.get(i);

            i++;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup() 
    {
        this.outputBag = BagFactory.getInstance().newDefaultBag();

    }

    @Override
    public DataBag getValue() 
    {
        return outputBag;
    }


    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input)
      {
        try 
        {
          Schema.FieldSchema inputFieldSchema = input.getField(0);

          if (inputFieldSchema.type != DataType.BAG)
          {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected a BAG as input");
          }

          Schema inputBagSchema = inputFieldSchema.schema;

          if (inputBagSchema.getField(0).type != DataType.TUPLE)
          {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Expected input bag to contain a TUPLE, but instead found %s", DataType.findTypeName(inputBagSchema.getField(0).type)));
          }

          Schema inputTupleSchema = inputBagSchema.getField(0).schema;

          Schema outputTupleSchema = inputTupleSchema.clone();

          outputTupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("previous_domain", DataType.CHARARRAY));

          outputTupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("next_domain", DataType.CHARARRAY));

          return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input),outputTupleSchema,DataType.BAG));
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) 
        {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        catch (FrontendException e) 
        {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }


}
```